# How can I go to href on tag with hide attribute value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I go to href on tag with hide attribute value?
here is my navigation bar

```js
$(function() {
  $('#p10').hide();
  $('#p11').hide();
  $('#p12').hide();
  $('#p13').hide();
  $('#p14').hide();
  $('#p15').hide();
  $('#p16').hide();
  $('#p17').hide();
  $('#p18').hide();
  $('#p19').hide();
  $('#p20').hide();
  $('#p21').hide();

  $('#hideshow').click(function() {
    $('#p10').toggle();
    $('#p11').toggle();
    $('#p12').toggle();
    $('#p13').toggle();
    $('#p14').toggle();
    $('#p15').toggle();
    $('#p16').toggle();
    $('#p17').toggle();
    $('#p18').toggle();
    $('#p19').toggle();
    $('#p20').toggle();
    $('#p21').toggle();
  });

  $('#navbarNav').click(function() {
    console.log($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link " href="#section2">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#p1">Subway congestion prediction app</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#p2">Image classification</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#p3">Community site</a>
    </li>
...
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#p17">Assembly</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#p18">Data structure</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#p19">Concave</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#p20">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section5">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When loading the page here, p10 to p21 are hidden.

In this situation, if you click from 10 to 21 of the navigation bar, it is hidden and you cannot move to href.

How can I remove the hide attribute when clicking p10 to p21 of the navigation bar (click the #hideshow button at the time of the hide attribute) and move to p10 to p21?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg " style="font-size:3rem; margin-bottom:100px; background-color:#3e454e" id="hideshow">Want to see more?</button>
```

#showhide button is between #p9 #p10

Comment: You try to select with jQuery IDs (10 - 21) but the HTML doesn't contain these IDs. Furthermore: The click event listener is assigned to an element with the ID `#hideshow` which doesn't exist.

Comment: If you see a pattern repeat - like a dozen almost identical 'select by ID' - chances are you can shorten your code. I would suggest marking all these elements with a class and then just writing $('.all_these_items').toggle() .. unless you use the nav-link class for other things you could write $('.nav-link').toggle() .. and actually - why not just do $('#navbarNav').toggle() - or create a container to toggle if you need the navbarNav container for some page layout !?!?!

Answer (score 0):

The jquery-selector is used in this way:

```
$('#<id>').hide();
```

-> the `<id>` (after the #) must be the id of the element. In your HTML it is the given href.
In your given code the #hideshow button is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You try to select with jQuery IDs (10 - 21) but the HTML doesn't contain these IDs. Furthermore: The click event listener is assigned to the button `#hideshow` which doesn't exist.

If you define the IDs and add the button `#hideshow` it works:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#p10').hide();
  $('#p11').hide();
  $('#p12').hide();
  $('#p13').hide();
  $('#p14').hide();
  $('#p15').hide();
  $('#p16').hide();
  $('#p17').hide();
  $('#p18').hide();
  $('#p19').hide();
  $('#p20').hide();
  $('#p21').hide();

  $('#hideshow').click(function() {
    $('#p10').toggle();
    $('#p11').toggle();
    $('#p12').toggle();
    $('#p13').toggle();
    $('#p14').toggle();
    $('#p15').toggle();
    $('#p16').toggle();
    $('#p17').toggle();
    $('#p18').toggle();
    $('#p19').toggle();
    $('#p20').toggle();
    $('#p21').toggle();
  });

  $('#navbarNav').click(function() {
    console.log($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link " href="#section2">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="1p17" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#p1">Subway congestion prediction app</a>
    </li>
    <li id="p2" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#p2">Image classification</a>
    </li>
    <li id="p3" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#p3">Community site</a>
    </li>
...
<button type="button" id="hideshow">Want to see more?</button>
...
    <li id="p17" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#p17">Assembly</a>
    </li>
    <li id="p18" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#p18">Data structure</a>
    </li>
    <li id="p19" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#p19">Concave</a>
    </li>
    <li id="p20" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#p20">Contract</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section5">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```